# Custom log4j configuration not working in jboss 7.1.1 EAR based application

Tags: jsp, servlets, log4j, jboss7.x

We have an application based on EAR. I have followed the approach given to the documentation as well as some other website. But still Jboss using the default logging. I need log4j to setup SMTP appender.

The application structure is :

```
MyApp.ear
|
|- META-INF
    |
    |- application.xml
    |- jboss-deployment-structure.xml
|
|- lib
    |
    |- *.jar

|
|- MyApp.war
    |- lib
        |
        |- *.jar
        |- MySecurity.jar
    |- WEB-INF
        |
        |- server-config.wsdd
        |- web.xml
        |- classes
        |- jboss-web.xml
|- MyEjb.jar
      |- com
```

I added a EAR META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml file with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
     <exclusions>
     <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
     </exclusions>
     <dependencies>
        <module name="com.test.logging"/>
     </dependencies>
 </deployment>
<sub-deployment name="MyEjb.jar">
     <exclusions>
         <module name="org.apache.log4j"/>
      </exclusions>
     <dependencies>
        <module name="com.test.logging"/>
     </dependencies>
 </sub-deployment>
 <sub-deployment name="MyApp.war">
     <exclusions>
          <module name="org.apache.log4j"/>
     </exclusions>
     <dependencies>
         <module name="com.test.logging"/>
     </dependencies>
 </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I added a module in jboss server like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.test.logging">
     <resources>
       <resource-root path="."/>
     </resources>
 <dependencies>
      <module name="org.apache.log4j"/>
 </dependencies>
</module>
```

I kept log4j.xml in the module

```
com
 |- test
   |-logging
     |- main
       |- log4j.xml
       |- module.xml
```

I have tried with keeping log4j.xml in EAR lib folder as well but still jboss is using the default logging.

Please help on this issue.

Comment: try removing all the exclusions in jboss-deployment-structure.xml

Comment: By "JBoss using the default logging" do you mean the container or your application?